# The right way to handle non-form fields in a request/response using spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Hibernate-based model object with, say, ten fields.   I need to pass six of them to a Spring form and get them back, but the other four don't need to make the round trip to the form.   However they DO need to stick around to get updated/created when the Hibernate object is saved in the database.   I'd rather not put them on the form as hidden fields if I don't need to, some of them have potentially sensitive data.

What's the best way to do this?   I have looked online for a solution but the information/examples are rather sparse.

I've been playing with creating an instance of the Hibernate POJO as a request-scoped Spring bean, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create a basic DTO using the six fields only, and then use the returned deserialized data to update the entity.

Or simply serialize the whole hibernate enitity out, and then deserialize back in and merge.

Up to you really as four fields making the round truip will really not make much difference. More likely security will be a concern.

In my app I set up a number of conversion services to automate deserialzation of entities.

DTO's are useful when presenting data from a number of different entities for use in one form.

Don't create a request scoped bean, thats overkill. The four unused fields will stick around, they are persisted in the database/stored in whatever hibernate cach.

Worry about your api design before optimzing

Answer (score 1):

My approach will be to a separate form backing object. Something along the lines of

```
public class ModelForm {
    //required fields

    public ModelForm(Model model){
        //set the values from model
    }

    //getters and setters

    public void update(Model model){
        //set values back to the model
    }
}

public class ModelController {
    public <return-type> submit(@ModelAttribute ModelForm form) {
        Model model = loadModel(form);//Load the model object from DB using a id or some other property
        form.update(model);
        //other logic
        save(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the attribute of model are not send to spring front end(form as hidden) you will lose the data , unless you are saving it somewhere (Session, StaticMap,database) Which can be a costly operation . If  don't want to hit database twice ,Put in a staticMap with Key as user and object id and value the old object.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting up the [second level cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-cache) in Hibernate for that entity, so that you don't have to reload the instance from DB when updating it with the properties received from the UI.